# Radio button value is always set as “on”

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I have the following fields in my form:

```
            <div class="col-12">
              <label>Esti de acord cu procesarea datelor tale conform celor de mai sus?</label>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gdpr" id="gdpr1" value="Da, sunt de acord">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gdpr1"> Da, sunt de acord</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gdpr" id="gdpr2" value="Nu, nu sunt de acord"/>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="gdpr2"> Nu, nu sunt de acord</label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

But always I get the value in the database equaling to a value of "on".

Is something that I'm doing wrong or should be done in another form?

Ok, some clarifications after your feedback guys.

Ok, so a few clarifications. "On" value doesn't mean anything to me. It doesn't appear anywhere in the code. Now regarding the PHP part, here it is:

```
if (isset($_POST["newFile"])) {

  // GDPR consent which goes into the client table   $gdpr = $_POST["gdpr"];
```

then it goes to the function createClient which looks like this:

```
  createClient($conn, $date, $name, $birthdate, $locality, $phone, $mail, $treatments, $gdpr);
```

And the database looks something like this:
[database-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT1OD.png)

Also, it doesn't matter what option I choose it is still going to insert "on" as a value in the database.

Hope this explains it better.

LE:

Here is the createClient function:

```
function createClient ($conn, $date, $name, $birthdate, $locality, $phone, $mail, $gdpr) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO clients (clientsDate, clientsName, clientsBirthdate, clientsLocality, clientsPhone, clientsEmail, clientsGDPR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("location: ../clients?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $date, $name, $birthdate, $locality, $phone, $mail, $gdpr);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some pointers on what should be included in a question. Right now, there's not enough information for us to identify the problem.

Comment: Two things you should clear up: 1) what does "on" mean for you (is it the affirmative value, "Da"?) and 2) share the code where you handle this form submission. You might also benefit from learning the [basics of debugging](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/).

Comment: _“Now regarding the PHP part, here it is”_ - where? Please do not post extended code in comments, edit your question and include it in there (properly formatted.)

Comment: You need to show the `createClient` function, because that's the one which does the actual database operation.

Comment: Edited the post and added the function.

Comment: Solved. Apparently I left another variable and it was taking the value of that. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you added, there's an error: The function signature doesn't correspond to the function call.

You call `createClient` with 9 params while the definition is with 8 params. Maybe the variable `$treatments` has the value "on"? As the value of `$gdpr` in the function implementation is what you have in the variable `$treatments` when you call the function

Comment: The cause of the problem was the passing of the $treatments variable?

Comment: Yes, that was the culprit.

Comment: Glad you found it. So, as I catched the culprit before your "solving notification", could you be so kind to set my answer as the accepted one? :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Apparently I left another variable and it was taking the value of that. Thank you so much guys. – Andrei Valentin Niculae 3 hours ago